# GLUQuadric Disk drawn but fill color is not solid

Tags: opengl, jogl

being a complete OpenGL newbie, I have a problem I do not understand how to solve. I am using JOGL, and trying to draw a disk, filled with a solid color and a different border color. My problem is obvious in the following image:

[image: gluquadric disk]

What I cannot understand is why I can still see the lines produced by GLU. The code that draws this is the following:

```
glColor3ub(r, g, b); // purple
gluDisk(quadric, 0, 50, 32, 2);

glColor3ub(r, g, b); // dark gray
gluDisk(quadric, 49, 50, 32, 2);
```

I suspect I have done something wrong with blending/anti-aliasing. When I disable anti-aliasing, the shape is drawn with solid color; however I need AA. I have set up AA and blending as shown below:

```
glEnable(GL2.GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL2.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL2.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

glEnable(GL2.GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
glHint(GL2.GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL2.GL_NICEST);

glEnable(GL2.GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
glHint(GL2.GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, GL2.GL_NICEST);
```

Finally, my GLCanvas is created with the following GLCapabilities:

```
caps.setAlphaBits(16);
caps.setDoubleBuffered(true);
caps.setHardwareAccelerated(true);
```

Other than that, the Quadric rendering properties are the default. Does anybody understand what have I done wrong? I apologize for any information that might be missing! Thanks for reading!

Ilias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH. Smoothing never worked painfree and artifacs like those you see are a result from that. A far better antialiasing method is multisampling. There's a tutorial at http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Multisampling